# Encrypted Coordinates

Tags: cipher, computer-science

I have a set of what I believe to be 4 (X,Y) points turned into a blob of hex

like so: `0x000080BFA8AAF340000080BF031AFE40FFFF3F41010D6741FFFF3F4153D56141`

Can you decipher and explain the encoding?

Comment: Do you know *how many* X,Y points there are in there?

Comment: I believe there to be 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers make more sense when interpreted as 32-bit [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating-point numbers, stored in little-endian byte order. The number -1 in this format has a specific value and it would be surprising to find its little-endian byte representation `0x000080BF` anywhere else.

```
-1.       ,  7.614582  
-1.       ,  7.9406753 
11.999999 , 14.440675  
11.999999 , 14.114581
```

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly basic, but I get the following four points:

- (32959, 2829775680)
- (32959, 52100672)
- (4294917953, 17655617)
- (4294917953, 1406492993)

Basically, just turn each coordinate from DEC to HEX and concatenate them all after the 0x prefix. Not really a cipher, but there ya go.

Comment: ^vote with questions: Do the coordinates outline a figure?  Might the coordinates be floating point? GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the text as 8 32-bit hexidecimal numbers, and using [2's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), you get:

```
+32959, -1465191616
+32959, +52100672
-49343, +17655617
-49343, +1406492993
```

I don't know if that helps.

They could be lat/long pairs, but I can't see how to convert the number raw value to a lat/long range, especially given the large values.